# Select Nodes using key() based on Condition

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0

I have a situation where I need to select the nodes based on certain conditions and then apply Muenchian grouping to get unique values. I am on XSLT 1.0

```
<Parent>
    <Child>
        <A></A>
        <B></B>
        <C></C>
    </Child>
    <Child>
        <A></A>
        <B></B>
        <C></C>
    </Child>
    <Child>
        <A></A>
        <B></B>
        <C></C>
    </Child>
</Parent>
```

The Condition that I have for use attribute is: 
If A is not blank, use A. Otherwise use B.

I had thought of a solution that would work for Fixed Width values for Node A and B. So If A and B are of length n, I can do something like this:

```
<xsl:key name="groupKey" match="/Parent/Child" use="substring(concat(A,B),1,n)">
```

So, If A is not present, I can use B. But I haven't been able to figure out how to use string-length() to derive the expression for variable lengths for A and B. Any Ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**In case you want to use the `concat()` function:**

```
use="concat(A, B[not(string(../A)])"
```

**And if by *blank* you mean empty or whitespace-only, then use**:

```
use="concat(A, B[not(normalize-space(../A)])"
```

**Finally, if you really want to use both `concat()` and `substring()`** (and this is really tricky, so I don't recommend it):

```
concat(substring(A, 1 div string(A) or 0),
       substring(B, 1 div not(string(A)))
      )
```

**Here is a complete example for the last case**, showing what the call to `concat()` returns:

**XML document**:

```
<t>
    <p>
        <A>xxx</A>
        <B>yyy</B>
    </p>
    <p>
        <A/>
        <B>zzz</B>
    </p>
</t>
```

**Transformation** (just outputs the results of the evaluated expressions):

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output method="text"/>

  <xsl:template match="p">
    <xsl:value-of select=
    "concat(substring(A, 1 div string(A) or 0),
            substring(B, 1 div not(string(A)))
            )"/>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Wanted (correct) result produced**:

```
xxx
zzz
```

Comment: use="concat(A, B[not(string(../A)])" is what I was looking for.

Comment: If I use `use="A | B[not(string(../A))]"`, The Muenchian grouping will treat the two cases I mentioned in my fourth comment on @michael.hor257k's answer as Different Sets. I wanted to match nodes based on string values rather than node-sets. Thanks again.

Comment: And as you mentioned, I can do any other string operations. As for the string-lenght() solution, it doesn't looks like the right thing for this situation.

Answer (score 1):

How about:

```
use="A | B[not(string(../A))]"
```

Comment: Would node-set classify as a valid expression?

Comment: @Madeyedexter I am afraid I don't understand what you're asking.

Comment: The value inside use attribute should be an expression, but the union will give me node-set.

Comment: I had a look at the XSLT 1.0 Documentation and the node-set qualifies as a valid expression. There is one more thing: Wouldn't the Muenchian Grouping treat a set of blank A and non-blank B and a set of Non-blank A as different nodes? I do not want to distinguish based on sets

Comment: @Madeyedexter Why don't you try this and tell us if it works or how it fails.

Comment: @DanielHaley  "*XSLT 1.0 is only going to use the first node in the union*" What makes you think so?  http://xsltransform.net/ej9EGcL

Comment: @DanielHaley I am not sure what the purpose of your test is. My point was to show that the key fetches any `Child` where either `A` has the key or `A` is empty and `B` has the key. I believe that was the requirement here.

Comment: Perhaps this will provide a better illustration: http://xsltransform.net/ej9EGcL/2 Note the 2nd `Child`, where `A` **is** empty and the key **does** use the value of `B`. -- P.S. Note that in your test, the `key` **attribute** in the `group` element will indeed only contain the text value of the first node. That may be misleading.

Comment: Thanks Michael. The value returned by the AVT is what was throwing me off. I'm going to clean up my comments and update my answer.

Comment: @DanielHaley Actually, you do have a point. The thing is that the `use` attribute of the `xsl:key` element evaluates to a node-set - but the second argument of the `key()` function is a string. The question was about the `use` attribute, so I ignored the ramification later on. So your correction would be necessary for the `key()` function, but not for the `xsl:key` element.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to walk me through that. I appreciate it. +1

Comment: This relies on assumption that `A` always precedes its `B` sibling. In general this assumption is not true and the key will be the string value of the *first* of these two nodes -- not of the one that is not empty. If both have non-empty string - value and `B` precedes its `A` sibling, then the value of `B` is used as the key -- exactly the opposite of what the OP wants. -1!

Answer (score 1):

Here's another option that uses a different `use`.

<kbd>[`Example...`](http://xsltransform.net/bFN1y9J)</kbd>

**XML Input**

```
<Parent>
    <Child>
        <A>both</A>
        <B>both</B>
        <C>c</C>
    </Child>
    <Child>
        <A>a</A>
        <B></B>
        <C>c</C>
    </Child>
    <Child>
        <A></A>
        <B>b</B>
        <C>c</C>
    </Child>
</Parent>
```

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output indent="yes"/>
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

  <xsl:key name="child" match="Child" use="(A[string()]|B[string()])[1]"/>

  <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="/*">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:for-each select="Child[count(.|key('child',(A[string()]|B[string()])[1])[1])=1]">
        <group key="{(A[string()]|B[string()])[1]}">
          <xsl:apply-templates select="key('child',(A[string()]|B[string()])[1])"/>
        </group>
      </xsl:for-each>        
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**XML Output**

```
<Parent>
   <group key="both">
      <Child>
         <A>both</A>
         <B>both</B>
         <C>c</C>
      </Child>
   </group>
   <group key="a">
      <Child>
         <A>a</A>
         <B/>
         <C>c</C>
      </Child>
   </group>
   <group key="b">
      <Child>
         <A/>
         <B>b</B>
         <C>c</C>
      </Child>
   </group>
</Parent>
```

Comment: Daniel Haley, Is my understanding correct, that this solution assumes that the `A` sibling will always precede the `B` sibling? In case the XML document has the siblings in any order, then one example, where the value of `B` will be used for the key although its sibling `A` has a non-empty string value, is a document containing this fragment: `           <Child>
             <B>Group B</B>
             <A>Group A</A>
             <Note>Belongs in Group A</Note>
          </Child>
` The other answer has the same issue.

Comment: @DimitreNovatchev - Yes your understanding is correct. +1 to your better answer.